# How to set collision bounds for Armature object

Tags: game-engine, physics, bones

I made a simple character in blender game engine. He's parented to an armature, so he can walk, ext. Now I want to make him a character, so he can jump, can't go through obstacles, have a step height. I think you do that by setting the armature to Physics type: character. And it kind of works. But the collision bounds are a box, so the character sinks into the ground.

here's a picture
[image]

The white box in the middle of a character is his bouning box. How can I fix that? I tried the collision bounds, but it doesn't work. No matter which one I chose, it had no effect whatsoever.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: check the box that says "collision bounds"

Comment: you would never really put physics on the armature, make a collision box for him.

Comment: checking 'collision bounds' doesn't work, even though it displays it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'make a collision box for him'?

Comment: make an actual box ie cube, scale it to the collision size you want. Make it a collision object, and parent the armature to the box (ie the box is the armature's parent so it follows the box's physics). Also make it non-renderable.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. I was just wandering if there's a etter way of doing it. Thanks anyways

Comment: @RokiPodpecan for that, see [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30754/how-can-i-update-a-meshs-physics-while-in-the-game-engine) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't apply the physic to your character's Armature directly** as **Armatures aren't recognized as an Actual model** object but only an unrendered object that makes your character's body part move (rig), If you want to make your character collide with other thing, try this:

- Make sure that your char's armature and it's model have **No Collision physic** assigned.
- Then, make a **Cube** and **resize it to match with your Armature/Character's size** and **Place it around your character**, *You can rename the Cube as "charbound" if you want*.
- Set the **Cube's** physic to **Dynamic** and then **Set the Cube as parent of your Armature (not the entire character)**.
- **Move the basic movement control** in **Logic Bricks** from your **char's Armature to the Cube**, but **don't move the Action or other Actuator more than Motion Actuator**.
- And at last, make the Cube Invisible (physic tab > enable Invisible button) and Box Collision Bound.

If you want to make him **"jump"**, try using **Servo Control Motion Actuator** in Game Logic. by adding **Z-axis Linear Velocity**, **Enabled Z-axis Movement** and **Adjust Z-axis Max/Min speed value** then it would jump, make sure you **activate the Collision Bounds** on **Physic Tab**.
 Alternatively, you can use **Character Motion Actuator** and **Enable "Jump"** toggle there *(Actually, I've never tried it. But I'm sure it can)*.

Comment: I moved to unreal engine 4 since i posted this question so it's no longer relevant for me, but thank you nonetheless. Maybe someone else will find it helpful.

Comment: Ahaha, I know someone my end up on giving up option other than continuing works with blender game engine. Anyway, may your game became the best game.